# How can i improve my class design for the following scenario to improve code

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a set of functions namely **A(),B(),C(),D()** and i have 5 forms namely **FromE,FormF,FormG,FormH,FormI**.

All the forms use **some** or **none** or **all**  of the functions from A(),B(),C(),D().

**What i am currently doing**

Created an interface **isetOfFunctions** consisting of A(),B(),C() and D() and some other properties which are to be used by all the forms implementing it in every form that is FormE,FormF,FormG,FormH and FormI

**The Problem**

1.FormE does not use any functions

2.FormF uses only A(),B(),C().

3.FormG uses all the functions.

4.FormI uses B(),C()

```
public interface isetOfFunction
{
   public int neededinAllForm
   { get;set;}
   void A();
   void B();
   void C();
   void D();
}
//None of the functions are needed
public class E:Form,isetOfFunction
{
   public int neededinAllForm
   { get;set;}
   public void A()
   {
   }
   public void B()
   {
   }
   public void C()
   {
   }
   public void D()
   {
   }

}
//Only A() and B() are needed
public class F:Form,isetOfFunction
{
   public int neededinAllForm
   { get;set;}
   public void A()
   {
   }
   public void B()
   {
   }
   public void C()
   {
   }
   public void D()
   {
   }

}
```

Note: I can have more forms which have different combinations from the set of functions provided.

My current design makes makes the code to implement all the functions even though its not required.

I felt that i could use strategy pattern but couldn't come up with a solution.

kindly help me out 
also provide some tutorial if possible

Comment: I'm wondering when I saw your comment to one of the answers and also then the same info in the question: Is there any specific reason why these classes that are going to be used inside forms as far as I understand your question at least  are inheriting form form?

Comment: Do you specifically want an interface? Why not an abstract base class?

Comment: @ZevSpitz No i need not have an interface if not needed.Can you please explain your approach .?

Comment: @Thomas Yes yes i have a GUI build with texboxes and buttons and alot of controls thats why its inheriting from "form".

Comment: do you use these classes to just store the boxes and buttons or are they really part of the forms themselves? (if the former then "Form" is not necessary as you can hold the variables in any class, if the later then yepp is necessary)

Comment: @Thomas yes yes they are a part of forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the functions are always the same, or the same in most cases, consider creating an `abstract` class that inherits from `Form` (let's call it `BaseForm`) and implements these functions. Then have Forms E-I inherit from this `BaseForm`. There will now be a single "base" implementation for all the functions.

If a particular form's function needs to work differently, you can mark the function in the base class as `virtual` and override in the inheriting class.

```
public abstract class BaseForm : Form {
    public int needAllInForm {get;set;}
    public void A() {
        //default implementation here
    }
    public void B() {
        //default implementation here
    }
    public void C(){
        //default implementation here
    }
    public virtual void D() {
        //default implementation here
    }
}

public class F : BaseForm {}
public class G : BaseForm {
    public override void D() {
        //form-specific implementation of D here
    }
}
```

Comment: :considering the solution given above class F and G would also have definitions of A(),B(),C() and D().Agreed that i can override it but then why have the implementation of any of the functions inside a class when i not needed.In the above scenario if i give "Fobject =new F; Fobject.A() // A shouldnt be accesible if its not needed.

Comment: @user3719037 But you only have to implement them as needed -- once in the base class, and in other classes if the implementation is different. Unless it bothers you to see it in Intellisense?

Comment: @user3719037 See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7178532/111794). This doesn't prevent you from doing `BaseForm F1 = new F(); F1.A();`, so I'm not sure how much it's worth the trouble.

Comment: how is it different from my current approach .? i still have to write the code definitions of all the functions and returning a default value when not being used right..? i have an interface which does the same thing

Comment: true i can do that but that's not required i don't want to have function definitions of those which are not needed inside the derived classes even if it returns a default value when not needed.

Comment: @user3719037 No. If you're using an interface, you have to write the functions over and over for each implementing class. If you're using an abstract base class, the functions only have to be written once in the abstract base class, and the inheriting classes will be able to use the functions in the base class.

Comment: ok so according to the solution above i should have return the default values inside the base class and have form specific function overridden inside each of the forms.have i understood it properly or are you trying to convey something different.?

Comment: This surely is an improvement on my current design thank you. but is possible to completely not have functions which are not needed ? i.e with refference to the above solution Not have the function A(),B(),C() from base class and have only D() inside class H

Comment: @user3719037 Why is it so important to you that a class **not** have a specific function? I don't think it's possible to share functionality like this via inheritance -- if a derived class inherits some functionality from the base class, then it must inherit all the functionality of the base class.

Comment: ok just wanted to know if there's another way to solve it but if not possible then the solution is ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should find out the combinations which are possible for each form. Worst case senario you would be creating 4 interfaces for A, B, C, D and then make couple ones which implements some of those 4. Something like `Interface IAB : IA, IB`

Comment: I strongly agree. The other solutions imply empty functions, which is a bad smell. Moreover, as far as I can see from what we know of the whole picture, you're likely to find good names for those interfaces. Although I suspect that a completely different design would be better here.

Comment: @PatriceGahide can you please suggest a different design which would be better.?

Comment: @user3719037 That was just a guess, we don't have enough details here. But without going into too much of it, Steve's solution is, IMHO, a very good compromise (and may very well be the best approach).

Comment: @PatriceGahide _The other solutions imply empty functions_ - Do you mean unimplemented functions? My solution has no unimplemented functions.

Comment: @PatriceGahide,@Steve : ok so i create 4 different interfaces and combine the ones which are needed like InterfaceAB and put the combined one inside the common interface "isetOfFunction" along with the common properties.? if so then This solution is good.It stops me from implementing the unnecessary functions at the same time provides the common variables needed but what about the class which does not implement any of the functions .?

Comment: Why should the OP need `InterfaceAB`? Each class could implement the appropriate interfaces -- `public class G : Form, IA, IB`.

Comment: @user3719037 Then it shouldn't have any connection to any of the interfaces. `public class I : Form` doesn't require implementing any functions.

Comment: @user3719037 Interfaces do not provide common variables. They define what functionallity an implementing class must have. E.g. Every class which implements `IEnumerable` must have a `GetEnumerator` method. But you cannot define fields on an interface. The benefit of an interface is that I can talk about something which implements `IEnumerable` as something which has the `GetEnumerator` method, without knowing the actual type of the object.

Comment: @ZevSpitz doing so would also stop me from using the property which is to be needed across all the classes "public int neededinAllForm
   { get;set;}" as mentioned is needed across all the classes.

Comment: @ZevSpitz ok so should i remove the common variable and put it inside the abstact class as mentioned by your answer

Comment: @user3719037 Yes nothing prevents you from using base types (abstract or not) with that solution, at any level you may find useful ("above" or "below" interfaces in the hierarchy). Also keep in mind that C# interfaces allow properties in its definition. I'm sorry I won't have any more time for that discussion in the following hours.

Comment: @ZevSpitz *My solution has no unimplemented functions*: it could in the base class depending on what is really needed, and in the best case some base methods will return default values which is not a good sign either. Some derived types will have nothing to do with those methods but they are here anyway. This is a form of violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @ZevSpitz *Why should the OP need InterfaceAB?* Just a side note, if think Steve was only giving an example of multiple interfaces implementation, but this can also be handy sometimes if the capabilities exposed by both interfaces defines a higher-level capability. If it can easily be named, then it is sometimes worth to name it and use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a Adapter-class that implements the whole interface `isetOfFunctions` (that provides all of your needed functions A-D). Make every method within this adapter-class virtual and leave their body empty. So you may or may not override it in the derived class. Now everything you should do is let every class inherit from your adapter (which is preferebly an abstract class).

Now if you want to define any of these methods within your form-classes just override it there.

```
public abstract class BaseForm : Form {

    public virtual void A() {
        // leave the body empty    
    }
    public virtual void B() {
        // leave the body empty    
    }
    public virtual void C() {
        // leave the body empty    
    }
    public virtual void D() {
        // leave the body empty    
    }
}

public class G : BaseForm {
    public override void A() {
        // do what you need to
    }
    public override void B() {
        // do what you need to
    }
    public override void C() {
        // do what you need to
    }
    public override void D() {
        // do what you need to
    }
}
```

Comment: the fact that he made it an interface probably means they dont share any thing in common. So it will be confusing to other developers when they see a public method is available for use while it is really throwing not implemented exception

Comment: @Steve sry i had missed the part where they share some common variables.I have edited my question.sorry

Comment: @Steve It doesn't have to throw a not implemented exception; it could return `null` or some other default value. In this case the return type is `void` anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: The solution is great.But the classes are already inheriting "form" how can i fix it.?

Comment: @Steve yeap, throwing exception is not needed. However the functions don´t need to return anything, since OP introduced them as void.

Comment: @ZevSpitz yes i am currently doing it like that but its makes alot of functions which gives "not implement exception" is it a good programming practice to do like that.?

Comment: @user3719037 let your adapter inherit from form-class instead. It may however implement the interface.

Comment: @user3719037 for the exception part as zev and him have both pointed out: It is not necessary to throw it as exception (mostly during design you do that though so that you dont forget to implement those methods but else if you are sure you dont forget you can just return a default value or in the case of return type void return nothing  instead of throwing the exception)

Comment: If I am anyway writing an `Adapter` abstract class, what do I gain by having an `isetOfFunction` interface? In the broader scheme of things it may provide better OOP design, but I get the feeling the OP is not at that point yet.

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you please give a code snippet i am not able understand.am sorry i am newbie.

Comment: Is plagiarism the highest form of flattery? At least edit your answer to say `Adapter` instead of `BaseForm`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz unfortunately the name Adapter implies the adapter-pattern, which is quite different from this.